understand clamped-mass modes and pinned-mass modes in frequency response of Euler-Bernoulli beam
The picture below shows the frequency response of the strain at the base (proximal end) of an Euler-Bernoulli beam, when actuated with random torque applied at the base (proximal end) from the paper: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1087617

There are two types of boundary condition:

clamped mass mode (fixed beam) means no rotation is allowed: $\frac{\partial w(x,t)}{\partial x}|_{x=0}=0$
pinned mass mode(simple beam): no rotation is allowed, no reactive moment, so $\frac{\partial ^2w(x,t)}{\partial^2 x}|_{x=0}=0$

I know how to calculate the eigen-frequencies for each of the two boundary condition cases above, but in the paper, it reads, the picture is from real experiment measurements (beam being clamped), the peak of the spectrum correspond to clampped-mass mode, the valley correspond to pinned-mass mode. Could someone explain why?
I guess the spectrum is the FFT of the time course of the strain at base? The paper only mentioned random torque is used. So i don't really know how the time course of the strain at base looks like, and i dont understand what correspond to peak and valley of FFT.
I could understand "Peaks represent frequencies that are strongly present in the signal. The horizontal location of a peak indicates the frequency, while the height of the peak shows the amplitude or strength of that frequency component.
Valleys or low points in the spectrum represent frequencies that are absent or have very low amplitude in the signal."  But now we have a random actuation/stimulation signal, this still holds?
What are the area between the peak and valley then?

"pinned mass mode(simple beam): no rotation is allowed, no reactive moment" Nope. Should read "pinned mass mode(simple beam): no deflection is allowed, no reactive moment".  Sadly I cannot access that paper, so I'm not going to comment on the very odd claim about the graph.

I could not access the paper, but I'm fairly sure the logic would be as follows:
Remember Euler Bernoulli beam equation $M = -EI \frac{d^2w}{dx^2}$
You have strain gages at the base of a beam.  They will be measuring strain in response to a moment in the beam.  Remember $\sigma = My / I$ and $\sigma = E \epsilon$
So if your strain gages measure zero (i.e. the valley in the graph), then you must have zero moment, therefore $\frac{d^2w}{dx^2}$ must be zero, therefore the frequency must correspond a frequency that satisfies the given pinned-mass boundary condition.
I think strictly speaking this would only hold for an undamped system.  So experimentally the result might be affected a little bit if damping is high.  But if damping is low the affect would be small.

Thanks. I don't really understand if strain gauges measures zero, how that correspond to the valley in the spectrum? I guess the spectrum is the FFT of the time course of the strain at base? The paper only mentioned random torque is used. So i don't really know how the time course of the strain at base looks like, and i dont understand what correspond to peak and valley of FFT

I could understand "Peaks represent frequencies that are strongly present in the signal. The horizontal location of a peak indicates the frequency, while the height of the peak shows the amplitude or strength of that frequency component.
Valleys or low points in the spectrum represent frequencies that are absent or have very low amplitude in the signal."  But now we have a random actuation/stimulation signal, this still holds?
What are the area between the peak and valley then?

Without being able to see the paper frankly the term pinned mass seems unintelligible.

@Daniel K, what does y mean in your formula?

@sunxd in "sigma=My/I", y is the distance from the neutral axis.  The valley of the graph is not exactly zero, but it is very very small. It is a log scale so the valley is 100x-1000x smaller than the peak.  This is because it is a real world experiment.  For a theoretical curve (without damping) the valley would be exactly zero.  For real world it is not.  I think you have some very fundamental questions about vibrations and mechanics.  I would recommend a good textbook on Vibrations (perhaps Rao) and one on Strengths of Materials (e.g. Hibbeler).
